# How to change jtable cell Background Dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

I am having a `JTable table1` with 5 rows and 5 columns, and I would like to
change the background color of 3rd column/cell of 2nd row, when I call a function like

> changeBgColor(row,col);

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override [prepareRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29) method for doing that.

**Example:**

```
public Component prepareRenderer (TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){  
    Component componenet = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);  

    if(rowIndex % 2 == 0) {  
       componenet.setBackground(Color.RED);  
    } else {
       componenet.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    return componenet;
}
```

Here I am coloring all the rows at even positions as `RED` and all the rows at odd positions as `GREEN`.

As far as your problem is considered. Use the same approach just use a constraint stating,

```
if(rowIndex == 2 && columnIndex == 3) {
   componenet.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Other than the above stated cell all the cells will get the default color.